# Auto-generated build folder too long on jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins set up to run builds on a windows slave.

In an older version of Jenkins (2.7 to be exact), the builds ran fine under

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\<repository name>\<project name>\<stage>
```

However when we upgraded (now using 2.19.3), the builds are now under

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\<a concatenation of repository, project, stage and a *very* long alphanumeric string>
```

This causes problems in my build as filepaths are becoming too long to handle and various steps are breaking. In fact, even the default folder name is so long that the beginning of the name is being truncated.

There are Linux agents under this Jenkins master so I cannot do a blanket workspace change on all agents.

How can I proceed? Is it possible to change this default folder name to something shorter?

Answer (score 1):

So far, our solution has been a rather hacky one:

We simply mapped the long base folder to a network drive (specifically:

```
subst x: .
x:
```

and then continued on from there.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to set the workspace path manually in the Jenkinsfile, created from the sanitized form of the branch name:

```
    if (branchName) {    // if this build has the branch name set
    path = path.split(pathSeparator)    // take the current path
    def currentWs = path[-1] // -1 as index denotes the first item from the end (the last one)
    def workspaceRoot = path[0..<-1].join(pathSeparator)    // joins all path elements from 0 to (not including) the last, effectively stripping the last path part with hte crazy-long alphanumeric ID
    // Here is where we make branch names safe for directories by replacing all special characters except '_' with '_'
    // Of concern are the list of non-permitted characters for windows (/\:*?"<>|) and - for linux, but it's easier to replace all non-word characters
    def newWorkspace = env.BRANCH_NAME.replaceAll("\\W", '_')
    if (newWorkspace.length() > 61) {
        newWorkspace = newWorkspace.substring(0,61)    // trim the overall length to 60 characters - even though git doesn't have a limit, OSes do have.
    }
    if (currentWs =~ '@') {    // Add on the '@n' suffix if it was there
        newWorkspace = "${newWorkspace}@${currentWs.split('@')[-1]}"
    }
    path = "${workspaceRoot}${pathSeparator}${newWorkspace}"
}
ws(path) {    // Do the build-related stuff here in the newly composed, safe and short workspace directory
```